# ошибка с отображением управляющих кнопок в GridView

Tags: yii2

в индексе в виджете  GridView пытаюсь добавить свою кнопку вот таким образом

```
 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' =>  '{edit}',
            'buttons' => [
                'edit' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return Html::a('Изменить', Url::to(['image/index', 'id' => $model->id]));
                }
            ],
```

выдает такую ошибку 
Setting unknown property: yii\grid\DataColumn::edit 
в чем проблема понять не могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' =>  '{create} {edit}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'edit' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a('Изменить', Url::to(['aboutcat/upedate', 'id' => $model->id],['class'=>'primary']));
                    }
                ],
        ],
```

оказывается это тоже массив